# Python3 Pass Command Equivalent in Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, unix, scripting, python-3.x

Python3 has a *pass* command that does nothing. This command is used in if-constructs because python requires the programmer to have at least one command for *else*. Does Ruby have an equivalent to python3's *pass* command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, when you want something empty, you write nothing in there in
Ruby, since it's empty.

```
def some_function()
end
```

No need for any placeholder like "pass" for nothing.

Comment: This makes since. I like your simple, but yet effective answer.

Comment: some_function as defined above returns nil. which may not be the same thing as python's null pass operation, depending on how you have written your ruby code.

Answer (score 6):

Your statement is essentially wrong, since **else** statement is not obligatory in Python.

One of the frequent uses of the **pass** statement is in **try**/ **except** construct, when exception may be ignored.

**pass** is also useful when you define API - and wish to postpone actual implementation of classes/functions.

EDIT:
One more frequent usage I haven't ,mentioned - defining user exception; usually you just override name to distinguish them from standard exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

No, ruby does not have have `pass` statement you would simply not write it.

```
def function
    if something == 10
    end
end
```

is equivalent to

```
def function:
    if something == 10:
       pass
```

Comment: You don't need the `:` in Ruby in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need it in ruby ... an if doesn't require an else.